# Stream Zeros with Django with StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I have to send an amount of Zeros as response, defined by the request. They have to be plain zeros.
(I know, a rather odd task...)

so, for example, you need 100mb of zeros, you query `?size=100&unit=mb`, you will get a stream of 100mb only zeros.

Since it can be up to 16gb of zeros, I do not want to generate them at first, rather generate a stream of zeros and send this "line by line".

This is what I came up with, but it does not behave like I want because it first gathers the full data and then sends it.

```py
class CreateImageAndResponseView(View):
    line_count = 0

    def get(self, request):
        size_str = request.GET.get('size', '')
        unit = request.GET.get('unit', '').lower()

        if unit not in ('gb', 'mb'):
            return HttpResponse(status=400)

        try:
            size = float(size_str)
            if unit == 'gb':
                size_bytes = int(size * 1024**3)
            else:
                size_bytes = int(size * 1024**2)
        except ValueError:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)

        self.line_count = size_bytes // 1024

        return StreamingHttpResponse((b'0' * 1024 for _ in range(0, self.line_count)), content_type='application/octet-stream',)
```

I already saw [Problem with Django StreamingHttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75081932/problem-with-django-streaminghttpresponse), but I do not know which middleware could block this. Also, I am not running nginx or apache, just django from my console.

Comment: How do you know it is first all generated?

Comment: Do you use wsgi or asgi?

Comment: well, I have to wait until the response is coming. 10mb are coming almost instantly, 100mb are coming after like 10 seconds

Comment: no, as far as I know I do not use wsgi or asgi

Comment: But with what, do you for example use wget/curl to make the request. It is possible that the browser waits to render content.

Comment: tried with firefox, aiohttp and curl

Comment: ok, i have tried again with wget and it is working there.. but how can his be??

Comment: might be that the browser waits until it has all content (or a huge chunk) before *rendering* it (showing it on the screen).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working how it is supposed to be. But it is not because the server provide the response in a chunked way, that the browser will show it in such way. Indeed, a browser could wait until it has received all data, or for example a huge chunk before it actually shows something on the screen. After all if you would for example stream a video, it will not show the first half of the first image. It has logic in place to buffer a certain part of the video. Look if it has got enough to show a full image, and only then renders it.

If you work with a more low-level tool like `curl` and `wget`, you might see how the streaming response is received, and perhaps interleaved with logging if you would add print statements in the server.

Comment: yes it is, tried with another project using aiohttp and it is working there.

Thanks a lot!